# linux qt change monitor refresh frequency

Tags: linux, qt4

i am using openGL to improve the performance on the target.
i would like to know if there is a way to change monitor refresh frequency (from qt or linux) to match the application.

Answer (score 1):

Qt does not wrap that functionality. You would need to access X directly, via XCB (or Xlib, but XCB is to be preferred) and the XRandR extension.

However, these days refresh rate is typically limited by the output device, as LCD screens often only operate in the 60Hz-75Hz range.